# How do I handle the IOException if the Geocoder is not present?

Tags: android, google-maps

I do not understand what I need to do when the Geocoder is not present. Do I try to initialize the geocoder again or do I have to show the user a toast that informs them to restart the devices (which is not good practice I assume)?
`public void getAddress(double Lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); 
    try { 
        if (geocoder.isPresent()) {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not understand what I need to do when the Geocoder is not present."? Geocoder is a class and you can use getFromLocation() to fetch the location from latitude and longitude.

Comment: I mean what do I have to do when the IOException is caught? Do I have to  try to declare/initialize the geocoder object again or do I have to display the error using a toast?

Comment: Ideally it should not happen. If GeoCoder is catching an Exception you have to fix it. If it always fails than might be a reboot of device might return u the proper address again.

Comment: I do agree with you that it should not happen. However it has happened twice and both times I had to reboot the device. How to I fix it so that it does not happen?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting. This might be helpful.

Comment: Ok Saurav, I found an answer (https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) for my question. This is very useful however thank you for your time and effort, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and it is very useful.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

Comment: So now your geocoder.getFromLocation() is throwing exception ?

Comment: No it doesn't, what I did is I added code that checks if the addresses list is null and if its size is zero. If both these conditions are true I display a toaster, notifying the user that the address is not found.

Comment: Anyways its great if you find the solution and it worked for you. I was actually thinking about of original problem of how to deal with the exception when Geocoder is not working.